# Organizing Code in Java

Tags: java, android, structure, code-organization

my `main.java` file has a length of about 1000 lines. My code is getting more and more confused, and I would like to "split" it in different parts (e.g. in one file I would have essential stuff like `OnCreate`, in another file I would have for instance `GetHttpRequest`).

I already tried to put `GetHttpRequest` in a different class, but is there no simpler way? (It would take a really long time to adjust the code if I used this method)

Comment: the secret is to write it in a nice way so that you don't have to spend crazy amounts of time refactoring it

Comment: Very nice book on this is 'Clean Code' by Robert Martin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use classes and methods, and optionally packages.
This will solve your problem. There's no simpler way than that.

Comment: I'm sure OP uses at least one class and at least one method - so there *must* be a *little* more to it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not hard-code your program. There are several patterns on how to code a program, so it is efficient, everybody can easily read and understand it. I think you also have a "GUI", assuming to this, I recommend you to use the MVC pattern. It means Model-View-Controller, so you organize your program in Packages: "model", "view", "controller" and in those packages you put the classes. For instance, you have a simple Calculator. Then you have a class in view thats called "CalculatorView", where your graphical interface is and in controller you have your "CalculatorController" that works out the things like calculations. (You call the controller from the view) and you do not need model at all.

I hope that helps you. But you will have to rewrite all your code...